# Should it be "Who is it" or just "Who is" in "Who is it going to pay for it?"

Tags: difference, personal-pronouns

I was just talking with my family about selling a computer and my aunt said:

> But, *who is going to pay for it?*

And I wonder, shouldn't she have said it like this:

> *Who is **it** going to pay for it?* ?

Answer (score 1):

"Who is going to pay for it?" and "Who is going to buy it?" have the same literal meaning, and she could have used the second, but the first suggests that your computer isn't even worth any money. A more common phrasing is, "Who would pay for that?"

**New answer for newly revised question:**
"Who is **it** going to pay for it?" The first "it" here means nothing. We already have a subject, "who", and the other "it" is the only object in the sentence.

Comment: Thank you so much! And what about: the difference between who is it going and who is going?

Comment: Why do you think there should be an extra "it" in that sentence?

Comment: I don't necessarily agree with this. One can buy something without paying for it if someone else has supplied the funds. I feel like this distinction is pretty commonly made in everyday speech, e.g. "Go down to the store and buy some milk. I'll pay for it."

Comment: It's because I have been struggling with adding “it” to sentences and questions, and now in every single question/sentence I see, I wonder if I should add “it”. Do you have any tip for this?

Comment: @d_b Agreed, there is that distinction, but I don't see it as relevant to the OP's question, and possibly confusing to her.

Comment: @Mary, Can you give an example of a good sentence with an added "it" so I know what you're talking about?

Comment: Sure @gotube, for example:  “Eating ice cream it's delicious “, or “Eating ice cream is delicious” or another one “Their gossiping (it) is annoying”.

Comment: @Mary None of those are good sentences though. "Eating ice cream... it's delicious!" or "Their gossiping... it is annoying" would be OK, but that's not grammar, just writing down how people speak. The "..." part means they didn't finish the sentence.

Comment: @Mary Can you give me real life examples from native speakers, or from a text book?

Comment: @gotubem sure! I found one question in my book. Is it necessity that drives innovation? In this case, shouldn’t it be: Is necessity that drives? I also heard in a song this: Is it the look in your eyes? Or Is it this dancing juice? (Bruno Mars song)

Comment: In that example, "it" is the subject of the sentence. Do you know about subjects and verbs?

Comment: Ohhhh, yeah I know them, I thought that was the subject, but I wasn't sure